# How to do prediction with 2 inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to predict the model with 2 inputs. But It gives me a weird error. The code, graph and error of the graph are shown below.

The sub-model(x and y) run successfully. Once I concatenate these two model, I can't predict the result.

The model is: [image]

The code is:

```
char_input = layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype='string', name='Char')
char_token = char_vectorize_layer(char_input)
char_reshape = layers.Reshape((2,3), input_shape=(6,), name='Char_Reshape')(char_token)
x = tf.keras.Model(inputs=char_input, outputs=char_reshape)

word_input = layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype='string', name='Word')
word_token = word_vectorize_layer(word_input)
word_reshape = layers.Reshape((3,3), input_shape=(9,), name='Word_Reshape')(word_token)
y = tf.keras.Model(inputs=word_input, outputs=word_reshape)

combined = layers.Concatenate(axis=1, name='Concatenation')([x.output, y.output])


z = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x.input, y.input], outputs=combined)
z.predict([['i l o v e p y t h o n'], ['I love python']])
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1478 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1468 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1461 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1434 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:998 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:207 assert_input_compatibility
        ' input tensors. Inputs received: ' + str(inputs))

    ValueError: Layer model_18 expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>]
```

Success with x / y:

```
x.predict(['i l o v e p y t h o n'])
y.predict(['i love python'])

[[[8 3 1]
  [6 0 0]]]

[[[1 1 1]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inputs to keras models need to be a numpy array, not a list:

```
z.predict([np.array(['i l o v e p y t h o n']), np.array(['I love python'])])
```